# Put alias in Column using 1 table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

I have a 1 table column as below:

```
Column name: Money
Values: 40,50,60,70,80,90
Table name: Salary
```

Is there a way to put alias on column result?

I am aiming for like the result below:

```
| GROSS         | AMOUNT |
|Highest Salary | 90     |
|Lowest Salary  | 40     |
```

My current query is:

```
SELECT Money AS GROSS, Money AS AMOUNT
FROM Salary
```

I don't know how to put the ALIAS on Column.
Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Union query:

```
  SELECT 'HIGHEST_SALARY' AS GROSS,  MAX(MONEY) AS AMOUNT FROM TABLE1
  UNION
  SELECT 'LOWEST_SALARY' AS GROSS ,  MIN(MONEY) FROM TABLE1;
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for! I forgot about UNION!

Comment: But you could also use `UNION ALL` because you know you don't have to filter out any duplicates.